# Finding the mean of more than one vector

Tags: matlab

I am tring to get the mean of three vectors but the mean function is not working.

Example:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5];
B = [2 3 4 5 6];
C = [3 4 5 6 7];

V = mean(A,B,C); % should be [2 3 4 5 6] as each column is the some of the same column in A, B and C divided by three.
```

Any Help?

Comment: You should do: `mean([A;B;C])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a general case (row or column vector case), you can use this -

```
mean_vals = mean(cat(2,A(:),B(:),C(:)),2)
```